# I am facing an error while trying to load ResNet50 pretrained weights on my image captioning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

How to resolve this Error that I am facing?
`ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable 'conv3_block1_0_conv/kernel:0': Shape mismatch. The variable shape (1,1,256,512) and the assigned value shape (512,128,1,1) are incompatible.`

Code -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Input, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, add, Concatenate, Reshape, concatenate, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16, ResNet50, DenseNet201
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from textwrap import wrap

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 12
sns.set_style("dark")
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

image_path = '/Users/rohitsharma/Desktop/archive (1)/Images'

data = pd.read_csv("/Users/rohitsharma/Desktop/archive (1)/captions.txt")
print(data.head())

def readImage(path,img_size=224):
    img = load_img(path,color_mode='rgb',target_size=(img_size,img_size))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255.
    
    return img

def display_images(temp_df):
    temp_df = temp_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    plt.figure(figsize = (20 , 20))
    n = 0
    for i in range(15):
        n+=1
        plt.subplot(5 , 5, n)
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.7, wspace = 0.3)
        image = readImage(f"../input/flickr8k/Images/{temp_df.image[i]}")
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.title("\n".join(wrap(temp_df.caption[i], 20)))
        plt.axis("off")

def text_preprocessing(data):
    data['caption'] = data['caption'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
    data['caption'] = data['caption'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("[^A-Za-z]",""))
    data['caption'] = data['caption'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("\s+"," "))
    data['caption'] = data['caption'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([word for word in x.split() if len(word)>1]))
    data['caption'] = "startseq "+data['caption']+" endseq"
    return data

data = text_preprocessing(data)
captions = data['caption'].tolist()
captions[:10]


tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(captions)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
max_length = max(len(caption.split()) for caption in captions)

images = data['image'].unique().tolist()
nimages = len(images)

split_index = round(0.85*nimages)
train_images = images[:split_index]
val_images = images[split_index:]

train = data[data['image'].isin(train_images)]
test = data[data['image'].isin(val_images)]

train.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
test.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([captions[1]])[0]

model = ResNet50(weights='/Users/rohitsharma/Desktop/doc/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
fe = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[-2].output)

img_size = 224
features = {}
for image in tqdm(data['image'].unique().tolist()):
    img = load_img(os.path.join(image_path,image),target_size=(img_size,img_size))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255. 
    img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
    feature = fe.predict(img, verbose=0)
    features[image] = feature

class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    
    def __init__(self, df, X_col, y_col, batch_size, directory, tokenizer, 
                 vocab_size, max_length, features,shuffle=True):
    
        self.df = df.copy()
        self.X_col = X_col
        self.y_col = y_col
        self.directory = directory
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.features = features
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.n = len(self.df)
        
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.shuffle:
            self.df = self.df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n // self.batch_size
    
    def __getitem__(self,index):
    
        batch = self.df.iloc[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size,:]
        X1, X2, y = self.__get_data(batch)        
        return (X1, X2), y
    
    def __get_data(self,batch):
        
        X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
        
        images = batch[self.X_col].tolist()
           
        for image in images:
            feature = self.features[image][0]
            
            captions = batch.loc[batch[self.X_col]==image, self.y_col].tolist()
            for caption in captions:
                seq = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([caption])[0]

                for i in range(1,len(seq)):
                    in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
                    in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=self.max_length)[0]
                    out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=self.vocab_size)[0]
                    X1.append(feature)
                    X2.append(in_seq)
                    y.append(out_seq)
            
        X1, X2, y = np.array(X1), np.array(X2), np.array(y)
                
        return X1, X2, y
input1 = Input(shape=(1920,))
input2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))

img_features = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input1)
img_features_reshaped = Reshape((1, 256), input_shape=(256,))(img_features)

sentence_features = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=False)(input2)
merged = concatenate([img_features_reshaped,sentence_features],axis=1)
sentence_features = LSTM(256)(merged)
x = Dropout(0.5)(sentence_features)
x = add([x, img_features])
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)

caption_model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=output)
caption_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')


caption_model.summary()

train_generator = CustomDataGenerator(df=train,X_col='image',y_col='caption',batch_size=64,directory=image_path,
                                      tokenizer=tokenizer,vocab_size=vocab_size,max_length=max_length,features=features)

validation_generator = CustomDataGenerator(df=test,X_col='image',y_col='caption',batch_size=64,directory=image_path,
                                      tokenizer=tokenizer,vocab_size=vocab_size,max_length=max_length,features=features)

model_name = "model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_name,
                            monitor="val_loss",
                            mode="min",
                            save_best_only = True,
                            verbose=1)

earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta = 0, patience = 5, verbose = 1, restore_best_weights=True)

learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                                            patience=3, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.2, 
                                            min_lr=0.00000001)

history = caption_model.fit(
        train_generator,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        callbacks=[checkpoint,earlystopping,learning_rate_reduction])


plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

def idx_to_word(integer,tokenizer):
    
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index==integer:
            return word
    return None

def predict_caption(model, image, tokenizer, max_length, features):
    
    feature = features[image]
    in_text = "startseq"
    for i in range(max_length):
        sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
        sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], max_length)

        y_pred = model.predict([feature,sequence])
        y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred)
        
        word = idx_to_word(y_pred, tokenizer)
        
        if word is None:
            break
            
        in_text+= " " + word
        
        if word == 'endseq':
            break
            
    return in_text 

samples = test.sample(15)
samples.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

for index,record in samples.iterrows():

    img = load_img(os.path.join(image_path,record['image']),target_size=(224,224))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255.
    
    caption = predict_caption(caption_model, record['image'], tokenizer, max_length, features)
    samples.loc[index,'caption'] = caption
```

This error message is pointing to a problem with the shape of the arrays being used with ResNet50. It seems that  I am trying to assign values to a variable that has an expected shape of (1, 1, 256, 512) (based on the ResNet50 architecture), but the values I am trying to assign have a shape of (512, 128, 1, 1). This could be happening due to a mismatch between the architecture of my model and the shape of the data I am passing through it and I am not sure how I can fix this.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal example. Your error can probably be reproduced with a very few lines of code

Comment: Where did you get that h5 file?

Comment: I downloaded it from kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/keras/resnet50?resource=download&select=resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In the comment of the kaggle link is a link to other ResNet50 weights: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexisbcook/resnet50. For imagenet pre-trained weights, you can also use the one that comes with tensorflow.